# XML document parsing with DOM

Tags: java, xml, parsing, dom

I have an xml file as such:

```
element
 element1
  element1
element
```

Now: element1 can have text, or/and either/both of the two elements element2 element3 so the xml file could be

```
<element>
 <element1>
 hi hello etc
  </element1>
</element>
```

or

```
<element>
 <element1>
 hi hello etc
 <element2>
 how are you
   </element2>
  <element3>
    fine
   </element3>
  </element1>
</element>
```

I am successfull in parsing it when it is as in the above examples. i can access the nodes by their tags and get the content out of it. problem arises , when the xml is of the following form:

```
<element> 
<element1>
 <element2>
 how are you
   </element2>
  </element1>
</element>
```

I have a loop, that goes through the xml document and checks for the tags element1,element2,element3 and get the contecnt. for the above example i get an acception and the loops terminates. because when it reaches element1, it doesnt get a content,instead there ia another element.
    please help me solve this problem
    thanks

Comment: You should post the code too.

Answer (score 0):

If each line only contains element name or text content alone, I will use stack to parse
such context. so, define a stack S, and if the XML file as followings:

```
<element>
  <element1>
    hi hello etc
    <element2>
        how are you
    </element2>
    <element3>
        fine
    </element3>
  </element1>
</element>
```

So the whole idea may like this:

push `<element>`    --> S[`<element>`]

push `<element1>`   --> S[`<element>`, `<element1>`]
push `hi hello etc` --> S[`<element>`, `<element1>`, `hi hello etc`]
push `<element2>`   --> S[`<element>`, `<element1>`, `hi hello etc`, `<element2>`]
push `how are you`  --> S[`<element>`, `<element1>`, `hi hello etc`, `<element2>`, `how are you`]
Get `</element2>`, then Pop twice, and get `how are you`  --> S[`<element>`, `<element1>`, `hi hello etc`]
push `<element3>`   --> S[`<element>`, `<element1>`, `hi hello etc`, `<element3>`]
push `fine`  --> S[`<element>`, `<element1>`, `hi hello etc`, `<element3>`, `fine`]
Get `</element3>`, then Pop twice, and get `fine`  --> S[`<element>`, `<element1>`, `hi hello etc`]
Get `</element1>`, then Pop twice, and get `hi hello etc`  --> S[`<element>`]

Is this what you mean??